# Where dart benchmarks?

Tags: benchmarking, dart

Where can I see dart benchmarks (sources)?
I know about benchmark_harness, but i'd like to see more tests (NavierStokes, Splay etc).

I've seen that them mention in some issues, commits, blogposts, but I could not find them anywhere.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the benchmark sources haven't been released yet. We would need to clean them up first, and currently there are more important things to do. However we do plan to release more benchmarks over time.

Comment: I really very need next tests NavierStokes, Splay, Mandreel, Raytrace, I know that you have them. I am ready to help you to improve them if need.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at [Dart Performance](http://www.dartlang.org/performance/).

Comment: Yes, I know about it, but it contains the information only about Richards and DeltaBlue.